# Is possible get Exception type in a switch statement without using ToString?

Tags: c#

I need to check the type of the exception in a switch case, and perform different tasks for a specific exception, what I did for the moment is create a method that will be called when an exception is throw, so:

```
private static void ShuntException(Exception ex)
{
    switch (ex.InnerException)
    {
        case System.Net.WebException:
            DoSomething();
            break;
    }
}
```

essentially the problem's that I get this error:

> Error : 'WebException' is a 'type', which is not valid in the given context

I can fix this situation using `GetType().ToString()` and then writing the `Exception` type manually like so:

```
private static void ShuntException(Exception ex)
{
    switch (ex.InnerException.GetType().ToString())
    {
        case "System.Net.WebException":
            DoSomething();
            break;
    }
}
```

the last example that I added working well, but I prefer the first that doesn't working for the error displayed by the compiler, what I missing or I doing wrong?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: can you try: `case typeof(System.Net.WebException)` <-- removing .toString()

Comment: Switch on type? Nope https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/peterhal/2005/07/05/many-questions-switch-on-type/

Comment: So I guess I need to use the last method.

Comment: You could use the new `when` keyword where you caught this exception. `catch (Exception e) when (e.InnerException?.GetType() == typeof(System.Net.WebException)){ DoSomething(); }`

Comment: @TimSchmelter yes I know, but this is a different approach

Comment: if you have to use switch then you can't. but you can use with if statement. cause switch cases should be constant